# jQuery on click toggleClass of multiple elements found within specific div

Tags: jquery, css, video

My code toggles the class of .text and .video elements, but all on the page rather than just the one's in a specific div. I'm assuming something's wrong with how I'm using find(). The effect I'm going for with these functions is that clicking on an element with a blue border reveals a dotted border element associated with it. Click-ability then should toggle according to which element is fully visible and has a blue border, but I don't have that working either: both the blue and dotted border elements are clickable at the same time.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <div id="box1" class = "box"> 
                <p id="text1" class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ultricies ac est eu egestas. Etiam egestas elit blandit, mollis magna sit amet, consectetur augue. Aliquam quis elit ac ipsum maximus vestibulum vitae ac purus. Pellentesque vestibulum ante diam, vitae convallis urna tristique eu. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque pellentesque enim turpis. Integer efficitur lacinia felis eu sodales. Curabitur vestibulum faucibus sagittis. Aenean ut orci sem. Sed vel nisi pulvinar odio ullamcorper fermentum. Duis diam neque, volutpat id efficitur nec, commodo sit amet enim. Nam porta est eu turpis aliquet cursus. Vivamus tempor nisi sed odio rhoncus viverra. Morbi fermentum vitae risus ut porta. Cras scelerisque diam nisi, sed interdum lorem ullamcorper nec. Pellentesque auctor justo non tortor cursus, faucibus consequat ipsum mollis. Cras dui magna, volutpat sed nibh a, fringilla condimentum felis. Quisque facilisis, enim et feugiat eleifend, mauris nisi pulvinar massa, et sodales risus sem et mauris. Sed lacus leo, faucibus eget imperdiet in, dapibus vitae enim.</p>
                <div id="video1" class="video"> <video loop muted><source src=assets/IMG_1353.MOV></video></div>
        </div>
        <div id = "box2" class="box">
                <p id="text2" class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ultricies ac est eu egestas. Etiam egestas elit blandit, mollis magna sit amet, consectetur augue. Aliquam quis elit ac ipsum maximus vestibulum vitae ac purus. Pellentesque vestibulum ante diam, vitae convallis urna tristique eu. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque pellentesque enim turpis. Integer efficitur lacinia felis eu sodales. Curabitur vestibulum faucibus sagittis. Aenean ut orci sem. Sed vel nisi pulvinar odio ullamcorper fermentum. Duis diam neque, volutpat id efficitur nec, commodo sit amet enim. Nam porta est eu turpis aliquet cursus. Vivamus tempor nisi sed odio rhoncus viverra. Morbi fermentum vitae risus ut porta. Cras scelerisque diam nisi, sed interdum lorem ullamcorper nec. Pellentesque auctor justo non tortor cursus, faucibus consequat ipsum mollis. Cras dui magna, volutpat sed nibh a, fringilla condimentum felis. Quisque facilisis, enim et feugiat eleifend, mauris nisi pulvinar massa, et sodales risus sem et mauris. Sed lacus leo, faucibus eget imperdiet in, dapibus vitae enim.</p>
                <div id="video2" class="video" > <video loop muted><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"/></video></div>
        </div>
        <div id = "box3" class="box">
            <p id="text3" class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ultricies ac est eu egestas. Etiam egestas elit blandit, mollis magna sit amet, consectetur augue. Aliquam quis elit ac ipsum maximus vestibulum vitae ac purus. Pellentesque vestibulum ante diam, vitae convallis urna tristique eu. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque pellentesque enim turpis. Integer efficitur lacinia felis eu sodales. Curabitur vestibulum faucibus sagittis. Aenean ut orci sem. Sed vel nisi pulvinar odio ullamcorper fermentum. Duis diam neque, volutpat id efficitur nec, commodo sit amet enim. Nam porta est eu turpis aliquet cursus. Vivamus tempor nisi sed odio rhoncus viverra. Morbi fermentum vitae risus ut porta. Cras scelerisque diam nisi, sed interdum lorem ullamcorper nec. Pellentesque auctor justo non tortor cursus, faucibus consequat ipsum mollis. Cras dui magna, volutpat sed nibh a, fringilla condimentum felis. Quisque facilisis, enim et feugiat eleifend, mauris nisi pulvinar massa, et sodales risus sem et mauris. Sed lacus leo, faucibus eget imperdiet in, dapibus vitae enim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").find(".video").click(function () {
        $(".video, .text").toggleClass("toggle");
    });
    $(".box").find(".text").click(function() {
        $(".video, .text").toggleClass("toggle");
    });
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".video").hover(function () {
        $(this).children("video")[0].play();
    }, function () {
        var el = $(this).children("video")[0];
        el.pause();
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%:

}

.box {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

#box1 {
    border: solid 1px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 5%;
}

#box2 {
    border: solid 1px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 5%;
}

#box3 {
    border: solid 1px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 5%;
}

.text {
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    font: .9em courier;
    line-height: 160%;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px dashed;
    color: rgba(0,0,0, .2)
}

.video {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

video {
    width: 700px;
}

.toggle.video {
    border: 1px dashed;
    z-index: -10;
}

.toggle > video {
    opacity: .05;
}

.toggle.text {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    z-index: 10;
    color: rgba(0,0,0, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").children(".video").click(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("vtoggle")) {
            $(this).siblings(".text").toggleClass("ttoggle");
            $(this).toggleClass("vtoggle");
        }
    });
    $(".box").children(".text").click(function() {
            $(this).siblings(".video").toggleClass("vtoggle");
            $(this).toggleClass("ttoggle");
    });
});
```

Re-edited css:

```
.text {
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    font: .9em courier;
    line-height: 160%;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px dashed;
    color: rgba(0,0,0, .2);
    display: none;
    opacity: .8;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #bbb;
}

.video {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    z-index: 1;
}

video {
    width: 700px;
}

.vtoggle {
    border: 1px dashed;
}

.vtoggle > video {
    /*opacity: .05;*/
}

.ttoggle {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    color: rgba(0,0,0, 1);
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Partly! This solves the problem I had with toggling all elements on the page. But it still leaves both text and video elements of the div clickable at the same time. I think what I need is an if/else statement that checks for .toggle before running either function. If .toggle is true, then run the .text function as you've written. Else, run the .video function. Thoughts?

Comment: I think we need to make sure first that "it still leaves both text and video elements of the div clickable at the same time" isn't due to the fact the video and text elements are disaligned.

Comment: The video and text elements are purposefully misaligned in anticipation of my next task: removing fixed widths/heights/positioning so my page can adapt to any browser size. Also misalignment is appropriate for the page's aesthetic, but I digress. I'm trying to get the function to work regardless of element alignment. The Z-index might be the wrong path for me. Hiding elements could work, but I still want the elements to be partly visible with reduced opacity and a dotted line around them for UX functionality.

Comment: I was posing that the alignment may have been making it LOOK like it wasn't working while it was. And of course if there is a visible piece of the underlying div, it will be clickable unless you handle it with some code - i.e. "if the toggle/hide class is on, ignore clicks on this div".

Comment: I see what you're saying! Yeah, I'm having trouble coming up with that code. But you've given me a nice start by solving the problem of toggling all elements.

Comment: View answer again for new css.

Comment: yeah, same problems it seems: I can still click the underlying video div when the text div is on top, and the dotted border of the text div is invisible.

Comment: Aha! I got this to work. I added -10 z-index to vtoggle and +10 z-index to ttoggle to get the effect I need. Thanks again my friend.